# No sound in Ubuntu 13.04 i386

Tags: sound, 13.04

I have a machine running Windows 7-ultimate 32-bit. I installed vmware workstation on it and Ubuntu 13.04 i386 on that vmware. But on Ubuntu I don't hear any sound, any start up or movie or music sound. I have installed other OSes on that vmware but no one has that sound problem.

Comment: Did you try playing a mp3? You'd have to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `ubuntu-restricted-plugins` to be able to play them. However, you can play `ogg` or `ogv` without any additional plugins.

Comment: I'm novice in ubuntu. I installed it for first time and don't know the meaning of those terms. What the ubuntu-restricted-extras and ubuntu-restricted-plugins means and how to install them please?

Comment: Added an answer. Also, it's not `ubuntu-restricted-plugins`. It is `ubuntu-restricted-addons`. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to play `mp3` files and other proprietary multimedia formats, you need to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `ubuntu-restricted-addons`.

To do so:

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Run the following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras ubuntu-restricted-addons
  ```

Now try playing a `mp3` file and it should play just fine!

Comment: thank you very much. I'll try it and report the result back again. But, should I be connected to the Internet when running those commands or it's not needed?

Comment: @flyhipy Yes, you need an internet connection.

Comment: I did those. After working a while, terminal wanted me for agreement of something like "configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer" and at the end of this window, there is a "<ok>" but when I press the enter key for "OK", it doesn't get my enter, like that my keyboard doesn't work. but my keyboard outside of terminal window works. WHY WORKING WITH THAT SOFTWARE CALLED ubuntu IS SUCH HARD?

Comment: There is a small pop up window at down right corner when installing the ubuntu (when it boots and the ubuntu logo for first time appears and small dots under it blinks), which IMO is the reason of my problem. IT says "The default sound device can not be opened. A device ID has been used that is out of range of your system. Sound will be disconnected." And will vanish immediately.  No one can help me!!!?

Comment: Are you using Windows as your host system? If yes, you should look at [this](http://www.printandweb.ca/2012/10/fix-for-vmware-player-sound-problem.html).

Comment: I read that post. Since I don't use realtek so it didn't help me. I use the default windows audio device. anyway thanks.

Comment: What about [this](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/194708-no-sound-ubuntu-through-vmware.html)? You can search your problem on the Internet, there are plenty of solutions available on forums. Although, if you need any help, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much green7, you are a nice person. 1-I searched that issue on the web but didn't find many much related topics, except help.ubuntu.com which wasn't helper. 2-By manipulating the button of VM menu > removable devices > connect sound card, I could to get the sound back without installing realtek, but whenever I click on Sound Setting (on ubuntu) my selections on VM menu turn back and voice will be disconnected again.

Comment: 3- The solution of your last link was not obviously said (e.g., look at what is number "1)" saying there). although, after installing the realtek high denfinition, and by following the solution of your first link, the problem is solved, but still I'm looking for a solution without having to install the realtek to solve the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: @flyhipy Will look into it and reply back soon. :)

Comment: There isn't any suitable solution for my problem. And don't know why?

Comment: Try [this](http://communities.vmware.com/message/2227569). Apparently, it too requires installing a package, but it seems that the installation is required in the guest OS and not in the host OS.

Comment: I installed and ran the pavucontrol statement. No change occurred! Just like my prior comment (When I log in or want to change the sound setting -by clicking on sound setting- the sound again will be disconnected and I sound manually connect it). Anyway, Thank you very much for your much helps. I think this issue belongs to vmware workstation more than the ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

When it gets to the part where you need to press "ok" push [tab] or try an arrow key. Worked for me.